# Playing video on background, using cordova for android

Tags: android, cordova, video, background

I've created a cordova android application that stream video content from a ustream channel, and its working fine, I now want the app to keep playing the stream when its on a background. At the moment the video stream stops about 2 or 3 seconds after the app goes to background.

Is there a plugin that I can use to achieve that ? I believe this issue is not specific to ustream channels.

Thanks

Comment: How did you end implementing this? I need to do pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android platform has a right to passivate or terminate an application when it's no longer visible. If you need to perform actions when the application is not visible, you have to implement and register a service to do it. More information about Android services can be read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html